# Merging Dataframes in Python without changing index of first df

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, merge, datetimeindex

**Not sure why it's not showing tables for df1 and df2 in main post. I am able to see it in preview.**

I have two data frames df1 and df2. df1 has one column (row_no) and a DateTime index with freq = 'S'. df2 has normal indexing and has two columns (row_no, readings). Both data frames have the same number of rows. I want to join then using merge/join (like SQL) where row_no is the matching column, but I want to keep the DateTime index of df1 after merging.

df1:

|  | row_no |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-07-01 00:00:00 | 0 |
| 2022-07-01 00:00:01 | 1 |
| 2022-07-01 00:00:02 | 2 |

df2:

|  | row_no | readings |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0.1534 |
| 1 | 1 | 0.3091 |
| 2 | 2 | 2.3042 |

**Expected Output:**

|  | row_no | readings |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-01 00:00:00 | 0 | 0.1534 |
| 2022-07-01 00:00:01 | 1 | 0.3091 |
| 2022-07-01 00:00:02 | 2 | 2.3042 |

Currently, merging the two data frames is creating a new index, which I don't want.

Any suggestions would be really helpful.

[Screenshot of data frames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQ5oP.png)

Comment: what did you try? pandas has `.join()`, `.merge()`, etc. which can use `on=` like in SQL. You could show your code with example data in code.

Comment: I was trying join() and merge() both, but had issues with the Datetime index column in df2. The solution I got was using this code: df2.merge(df1, left_index=True, right_on='row_no')

Answer (score 1):

Use merge function along with index reset and set after matching your column(s).

```
pd.merge(df1.reset_index(), df2, left_on='row_no', right_on='row_no').set_index('index')
```

or

```
df2.merge(df1.reset_index(), on='row_no').set_index('index')
```

After resetting df1:

[image]

After merging df1 and df2 with 'row_no' column:

[image]

After setting the index:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I did find another solution which was:
df2.merge(df1, left_index=True, right_on='row_no')

I did try this before, where reset_index was used. But when setting back the DateTime index on new df, the Freq value is set to None. I need the "Freq" value to be 'S'. The above solution I tried worked.